# Stream.WriteByte() not working

Tags: c#, stream, uwp, animated-gif

I'm attempting to encode an animated GIF. I've managed to do everything, except write the Graphics Control Extension Block (which deals with animation delay and transparency). This is my current code:

```
StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(Guid.NewGuid() + ".gif");
var outStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
var encoder1 = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.GifEncoderId, outStream);

//FrameTimes is a list with the time of each Frame in my video file
foreach(TimeSpan ts in FrameTimes) 
{
    //Get WriteableBitmap from Frame
    List <byte[]> frames = new List <byte[]> ();
    var writableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    writableBitmap.SetSource(GetFrame(ts));

    //Get stream from the WriteableBitmap
    Stream stream = writableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
    byte[] pixels = new byte[(uint) stream.Length];
    await stream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

    //Encode frame to GIF
    encoder1.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, frameWidth, frameHeight, 92.0, 92.0, pixels);
    //This is where it's not writing anything:
    outStream.AsStreamForWrite().WriteByte(0x21); 

    if (ts != FrameTimes.Last())
        await encoder1.GoToNextFrameAsync();
}

await encoder1.FlushAsync();
progbar.IsIndeterminate = true;
await outStream.FlushAsync();
outStream.Dispose();
```

So the line that's not writing anything is `outStream.AsStreamForWrite().WriteByte(0x21);`. It's normally a void that writes a lot more stuff, but I've made sure the simplified replacement doesn't work either, as the file size doesn't change one byte, with or without that line. Any ideas as to what my stupid mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

`AsStreamForWrite` creates a new (managed) `Stream`, which has its own buffer. You'll need to flush/close/dispose this stream appropriately.

```
StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync(Guid.NewGuid() + ".gif");
var outStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
var encoder1 = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.GifEncoderId, outStream);
var netOutStream = outStream.AsStreamForWrite();

foreach(TimeSpan ts in FrameTimes) 
{
  List <byte[]> frames = new List <byte[]> ();
  var writableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(frameWidth, frameHeight);
  writableBitmap.SetSource(GetFrame(ts));

  Stream stream = writableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
  byte[] pixels = new byte[(uint) stream.Length];
  await stream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

  encoder1.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, frameWidth, frameHeight, 92.0, 92.0, pixels);
  netOutStream.WriteByte(0x21);
  await netOutStream.FlushAsync();

  if (ts != FrameTimes.Last())
    await encoder1.GoToNextFrameAsync();
}

await encoder1.FlushAsync();
progbar.IsIndeterminate = true;
netOutStream.Dispose();
await outStream.FlushAsync();
outStream.Dispose();
```

However, I'm not really sure if what you're trying to do will work. It looks like you're trying to write raw bytes to a file stream and *also* use `BitmapEncoder` to write to the *same* stream. Two writers on a stream is asking for trouble.